# React function style component direct invocation vs jsx - where is the children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to understand where is the children for the custom component jsx style?

```js
const appDom = document.getElementById('app')

const Hey = () => <div><i>HEY</i><b>you</b></div>
const Hello = () => <div><h1>Hello</h1></div>

console.log('ola', Hey()['props'])
console.log('hola', <Hey />['props']) // Where is children?


ReactDOM.render(<div>{Hey()}<br/><Hey/></div>, appDom)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the answer to your question, first, we need to understand what happen when JSX is transformed to normal JavaScript. The compiler simply rewrite your whole JSX markup tree with `React.createElement` method.

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

In this transformation to `React.createElement`,

- JSX tag will be passed as type,
- All attributes of the tag will be composed into one JavaScript object and passed as props and
- The content between the JSX tags will be passed as children after recursively applying `React.createElement` method on it.

This `React.createElement` returns a [React Element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) which is just a plain object.

So your Hey component will be something like follows in normal JavaScript form.

```
const Hey = () => React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(
    "i",
    null,
    "HEY"
  ),
  React.createElement(
    "b",
    null,
    "you"
  )
);
```

and your console log lines will be something like this.

```
console.log('ola', Hey()['props']);
console.log('hola', React.createElement(Hey, null)['props']);
```

Now if you look at these log lines carefully, what first line print is `props` of div react element which has two children; i react element and b react element. But the second line prints `props` of Hey react element which doesn't have any children. So it doesn't print children because it doesn't have any children. Basically,`Hey()` and `<Hey/>` are not the same thing even though what they render have no difference.

To understand it better, let's try another console log like follows,

```
console.log('hola', <Hey>abc</Hey>['props'])
```

which transformed to

```
console.log('hola', React.createElement(Hey, null, 'abc' )['props']);
```

This will still print `props` of Hey react element, but it will have children prop which is the 'abc' string.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense now.